# Excel Macro: If the final characters in each row of a column is "something", then

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to concatenate two cells if certain conditions are met in one of the cells.

Specifically: If the final characters in the cells of column D = " XX " then concatenate. I've done something similar to below and get an error each time.

```
Sub concatenate()
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = Last To 1 Step -1

    If Right(Cells(i, 4), 4) = " XX " Then
    'do some stuff to concatenate'

    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? Which two cells do you want to concatenate?

Comment: Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error...        Trying to concatenate the data in columns D&E if D has a certain ending...I'm using a blank column to create the concatenation and paste the value back in D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your reverse loop with some error control added.

```
Sub concat()
    Dim i As Long, l As Long
    l = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = l To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Then
            If Not IsError(Cells(i, 4)) Then
                If LCase(Right(Cells(i, 4).Value, 4)) = LCase(" XX ") Then

                    'do some stuff to concatenate'
                    'maybe...
                    Cells(i, 4) = Cells(i, 4).Value & " - " & Cells(i, 5).value
                    Cells(i, 5).clearcontents 'clears value; use Cells(i, 5).clear to clear everything

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Running string operations on an empty cell is unnecessary and could conceivably throw an error. Trying to run the same operations on a cell with an error will always throw a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`. You may have other special conditions that need to be accommodated but this should get you started.

Finally, direct string comparisons in VBA are generally case-sensitive; thus the conversion of both to lower case to remove case sensitivity.

Comment: @digitaura - after seeing your comment above, I've added code to run the concatenation of columns D & E in place.

Comment: Bonus points for helping me clear the contents of Column E in those instaces. :)

Comment: @digitaura - Please see code line added above. `.ClearContents` is analogous to tapping the `Del` key. Changing to `.Clear` will wipe formats as well as values. Record a macro using the various options in Home ► Editing ► Clear for some other possibilities.

Comment: That's WAAY more efficient than what I was doing. Thank you! :)

Comment: Here's a slight spin. Suppose I wanted to cut that ending in columnD and paste it into columnE?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub concatenate()

Dim myCell As String
Dim i As Integer

lastRow = Worksheets("yourSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1

    myCell = Worksheets("yourSheet").Cells(i, 4).Value

    If Right(myCell, 4) = " XX " Then
    'do some stuff to concatenate'

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```